# Multi-Dimensional List Sorting [multi-column]

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

The following code prints the student number and the students score.

```
def main():
    answers = [
        ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
        ['D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
        ['E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
        ['C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
        ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
        ['B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
        ['B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
        ['E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D']]

    keys = ['D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D']

    for i in range(len(answers)):
        correctCount = 0
        for j in range(len(answers[i])):
            if answers[i][j] == keys[j]:
                correctCount += 1


        results = [i,correctCount]
        print(results, end = "") # this line used to be - print("Student", i, "'s correct count is", correctCount)


main()
```

My goal is to sort the students scores from lowest to highest without mixing up the student number that's associated with that score.  I have attempted to use the sort function in these forms:

```
results1 = sorted(results, key = lambda x: x[1])
results.sort(key = itemgetter(1))
results.sort()
```

Using all three of these attempts I still am unable to make it work.  Any ideas?

Expected Output:

```
[3, 4]
[2, 5]
[1, 6]
[0, 7]
[5, 7]
[6, 7]
[7, 7]
[4, 8]
```

First Column is the Student #, second column is the score.

Comment: What is your expected output? You know you are overwriting `results` each time did you mean `results.append([i, correctCount])`.

Comment: Edited question to include expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't constructing a list of `results`, `results = [i, correctCount]` just overwrites the results, you need:

```
results = []
for i in range(len(answers)):
    correctCount = 0
    for j in range(len(answers[i])):
        if answers[i][j] == keys[j]:
            correctCount += 1
    results.append([i, correctCount])
results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Then your sorting code should work.

However, more idiomatically in python is iterating over the actual list vs. the `range(len(list))`, which can generally simplify your code, the above can be rewritten:

```
results = []
for student, student_answers in enumerate(answers):
    correctCount = 0
    for answer, key in zip(student_answers, keys):
        if answer == key:
            correctCount += 1
    results.append([student, correctCount])
results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Which is more readable than the original code.
You can also reduce it with the use of comprehensions and generators:

```
results = []
for student, student_answers in enumerate(answers):
    results.append([student, sum(ans == key for ans, key in zip(student_answers, keys)])
results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

And if you really want to go this far you could do the whole thing in one go:

```
results = sorted(((student, sum(a == k for a, k in zip(ans, keys)))
                  for student, ans in enumerate(answers)), key=lambda x: x[1])
# [(3, 4), (2, 5), (1, 6), (0, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Comment: The range in this case would be lens(answers[i][j])  correct?  I wouldn't need anything else but the results.append([i, correctCount]) in the body though correct??  (testing as we speak)

Comment: Very cool.  Pretty awesome how a whole paragraph of code, can be compressed into two lines.